# Python - simplify repeated if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, repeat

I am very new to python and looking for a way to simplify the following:

```
if atotal == ainitial:
    print: "The population of A has not changed"
if btotal == binitial:
    print: "The population of B has not changed"
if ctotal == cinitial:
    print: "The population of C has not changed"
if dtotal == dinitial:
    print: "The population of D has not changed"
```

Obviously _total and _initial are predefined.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hello! A minor point; don't forget your colons at the end of `if` statements. Good thing to get internalised quickly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use two dictionaries:

```
totals   = {'A' : 0, 'B' : 0, 'C' : 0, 'D' : 0}
initials = {'A' : 0, 'B' : 0, 'C' : 0, 'D' : 0}
for k in initials:
    if initials[k] == totals[k]:
        print "The population of {} has not changed".format(k)
```

A similar way is first determining not changed populations:

```
not_changed = [ k for k in initials if initials[k] == totals[k] ]
for k in not_changed:
    print "The population of {} has not changed".format(k)
```

Or, you can have a single structure:

```
info = {'A' : [0, 0], 'B' : [0, 0], 'C' : [0, 0], 'D' : [0, 0]} 
for k, (total, initial) in info.items():
    if total == initial:
        print "The population of {} has not changed".format(k)
```

Comment: I would prefer a dictionary of pairs. Or if the data is more interesting, a custom class and a dictionary of such objects.

Comment: Indeed, having a list of 3-tuples would allow you to avoid the dicionary lookups in `not_changed`, i.e. `not_changed = (name for name, initial, total if initial == total)`.

Comment: @rodrigo Can you please show me in terms of my example above.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe How would this look in terms of my example above?

Comment: @user3619552: Indeed! Now I do like it!

Comment: @perreal Sorry for simple questions - what is k used above?

Comment: @rodrigo What is k above?

Comment: @user3619552:  `k` is the key of the dictionary, that is, the letter. `(total, ìnitial)` is the pair of values.

Comment: @rodrigo This is what I have currently but nothing happens?

Answer (score 1):

You could organize all the pairs into a dictionary and cycle though all the elements:

```
    populations = { 'a':[10,80], 'b':[10,56], 'c':[90,90] }

    for i in populations:
        if populations[i][1] == populations[i][0]:
            print(i + '\'s population has not changed')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (2.7) using an ordered dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = OrderedDict((var_name,eval(var_name)) 
              for var_name in sorted(['atotal','ainitial','btotal','binitial']))
while True:
    try:
         init_value = a.popitem(last=False)
         total_value = a.popitem(last=False)
         if init_value[1] == total_value[1]:
             print ("The population of {0} has "
                    "not changed".format(init_value[0][0].upper()))
    except:
         break
```